# WiX Instance Transform fails with error code 2229 when using MajorUpgrade and Version binder

Tags: wix

I am using WiX to create a multi instance installer. The msi I generate installs the default instance correctly, but fails when I attempt to install a transform instance.

In trying to isolate the issue, I find that the problem seems to be related to an interaction between the MajorUpgrade tag and my use of a FileVersion binder variable for the Product Version attribute.

My test code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" 
           Name="TestArea" 
           Language="1033" 
           Version="!(bind.FileVersion.ExeFile)" 
           Manufacturer="Company"
           UpgradeCode="1C0E8BC6-6BD8-4A9D-9A36-14A898E4391B">

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A more recent version is already installed." />

        <MediaTemplate />

    <Property Id="INSTANCEID" Value="Default" Secure="yes" />

    <InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
      <Instance Id="Install2" ProductCode="*" UpgradeCode="38C61306-2B32-4475-A889-716BCBF196CA" ProductName="Instance 2" />
    </InstanceTransforms>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="TestArea" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLDIR'>
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="TestArea" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
             <Component Id="ProductComponent">
         <File Id="ExeFile" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\MyFolder\MyFile.exe" />
             </Component> 
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

When I run `msiexec /i TestInstall.msi`, the default instance is installed correctly.

When I run `msiexec /i TestInstall.msi MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=":Install2"`, I get the message:

> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this
>   package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code
>   is 2229.

If I run with a verbose log, the error shows as "Could not load table 'Upgrade' in SQL query":

```
Action: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start: FindRelatedProducts.
Transforming table Upgrade.
Note: 1: 2251 2:  3: Upgrade 
Note: 1: 2229 2:  3: Upgrade 4: SELECT `UpgradeCode`,`VersionMin`,`VersionMax`,`Language`,`Attributes`,`ActionProperty` FROM `Upgrade` 
DEBUG: Error 2229:  Database: . Could not load table 'Upgrade' in SQL query: SELECT `UpgradeCode`,`VersionMin`,`VersionMax`,`Language`,`Attributes`,`ActionProperty` FROM `Upgrade`
```

However, if I remove the MajorUpgrade tag, the second instance also installs correctly.

Additionally, if I replace Version="!(bind.FileVersion.ExeFile)" with a hardcoded value, such as Version="3.3.3.3", the second instance, again, also installs correctly.

What is causing this error? What should I do in order to install the instance transform, since I want to keep both the MajorUpgrade and Version binder that seem to be conflicting?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that your transform has most likely created a table that is incorrect. That error is "Database: [2]. Could not load table '[3]' in SQL query: [4]." so if you don't have the rest of the error information (the table name and query) in the message then do the install with a verbose log and it should tell you what table was incorrect and the query being used. Or load the MSI into Orca, use the menu to apply the transform and take a look at the file table version to see if it's valid, or whatever else was changed by the transform. If it's not doing a major upgrade it may not care about file versions (because it doesn't need to apply file overwrite rules) so that may be why it's ok without major upgrading.

It's not clear to me why you are doing this with a transform. I believe WiX can apply versions from variables at build time.

Comment: The log says the error is `DEBUG: Error 2229:  Database: . Could not load table 'Upgrade' in SQL query: SELECT UpgradeCode, VersionMin, VersionMax, Language, Attributes, ActionProperty FROM Upgrade`. I've opened the MSI in Orca, but I don't have a separate transform file, so I don't know how to apply the same transform the InstanceTransforms tag creates.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not using the transform to set the version. I'm setting the version with "!(bind.FileVersion.ExeFile)". I am doing multiple instances for other reasons, and it just happens that the instance doesn't seem to like the Version's binder variable.

Comment: Well you need to see what the modified Upgrade table looks like because apparently it's incorrect after the transform is applied. You need to find out what it looks like with the transform applied. There's no way to guess what's wrong with the Upgrade table given the information so far.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* be a bug in WIX.

I ran into the same issue.

After an investigation (extracting the Transform from the MSI and applying it with ORCA) I found that "!(bind.FileVersion.ExeFile)" is stored in the Upgrade table i.s.o the actual version number.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be logged as a bug against the linker/light.exe, as per [issue 4675](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4675).
@Dawid Mostert, it would be nice to know how to extract the transform from the MSI. I have had a quick look around and could not find the incantation.